# Azure combiner function to receive and write the same to Azure blob storage using Python

Tags: python-3.x, azure, http, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I want to create a Azure function using Python which will read data from the Azure Event Hub.
Fortunately, Visual Studio Code provides a way to create to create Azure functions skeleton. That can be edited according to the requirement.
I am able to create a demo HTTP trigger Azure Function with the help of a Microsoft Documentation but I don't know what change I should made in the below function so that it can read the data from the event hub and write the same to Azure Blob Storage.
Also, if someone can refer suggest any blog to get more details on azure function and standard practice.

## **UPDATE:**

I tried to update my code based on suggestion of @Stanley but possibly it need to update in code.
I have written following code in my Azure function.

**local.settings.json**

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "Storage account connection string",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "EventHub_ReceiverConnectionString": "Endpoint Connection String of the EventHubNamespace",
    "Blob_StorageConnectionString": "Storage account connection string"
  }
}
```

**function.json**

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "type": "eventHubTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "event",
      "eventHubName": "pwo-events",
      "connection": "EventHub_ReceiverConnectionString",
      "cardinality": "many",
      "consumerGroup": "$Default",
      "dataType": "binary"
    }
  ]
}
```

****init**.py**

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func
from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient

storage_connection_string='Storage account connection string'
container_name = ''


def main(event: func.EventHubEvent):
    logging.info(f'Function triggered to process a message: {event.get_body().decode()}')
    logging.info(f'  SequenceNumber = {event.sequence_number}')
    logging.info(f'  Offset = {event.offset}')
    blob_client = BlobClient.from_connection_string(storage_connection_string,container_name,str(event.sequence_number) + ".txt")
    blob_client.upload_blob(event.get_body().decode())
```

Following is the screenshot of my blob container:
[image]

After executing he above code something got written to blob containers.
but instead of txt file it got saved in some other format. also, if I trigger azure function multiple time then files are getting overwritten.
I want to perform append operation instead of overwrite.
Also, I want to save my file in user defined location. Example: **container/Year=/month=/date=**
Thanks !!

Comment: Microsoft docs is a great source for information overall but it is quite massive if you want to read it all. What you want is binding. Specifically a Event Hub trigger and blob storage output binding.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs-trigger?tabs=python#example

         https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-output?tabs=python#example

Comment: Have you tried this ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-capture-overview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to read data from the Azure Event Hub, using the [event hub trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs-trigger?tabs=python) will be much easier, this is my test code (read data and write into storage):

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func
from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient
import datetime

storage_connection_string=''
container_name = ''

today = datetime.datetime.today()


def main(event: func.EventHubEvent):
    logging.info(f'Function triggered to process a message: {event.get_body().decode()}')
    logging.info(f'  SequenceNumber = {event.sequence_number}')
    logging.info(f'  Offset = {event.offset}')

    blob_client =  BlobClient.from_connection_string(
        storage_connection_string,container_name,
    str(today.year) +"/" + str(today.month) + "/" + str(today.day) + ".txt")

blob_client.upload_blob(event.get_body().decode(),blob_type="AppendBlob")
```

I use the code below to send events to the event hub:

```
import asyncio
from azure.eventhub.aio import EventHubProducerClient
from azure.eventhub import EventData

async def run():
    # Create a producer client to send messages to the event hub.
    # Specify a connection string to your event hubs namespace and
    # the event hub name.
    producer = EventHubProducerClient.from_connection_string(conn_str="<conn string>", eventhub_name="<hub name>")
    async with producer:
        # Create a batch.
        event_data_batch = await producer.create_batch()

        # Add events to the batch.
        event_data_batch.add(EventData('First event '))
        event_data_batch.add(EventData('Second event'))
        event_data_batch.add(EventData('Third event'))

        # Send the batch of events to the event hub.
        await producer.send_batch(event_data_batch)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(run())
```

My `local.settings.json`:

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "<storage account conn str>",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
        "testhubname0123_test_EVENTHUB": "<event hub conn str>"
    }
}
```

My `function.json` just as [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs-trigger?tabs=python) indicated:

```
{
    "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
    "bindings": [{
        "type": "eventHubTrigger",
        "name": "event",
        "direction": "in",
        "eventHubName": "test01（this is my hubname, pls palce yours here）",
        "connection": "testhubname0123_test_EVENTHUB"
    }]
}
```

**Result**

Run the function and send data to the event hub using the code above:
[image]

Data has been saved into storage successfully:

[image]

Download .txt and check its content we can see that 3 event content  has been written:
[image]

Comment: can you please explain which set of code of extracting the data from the event hub.. if possible also share the reference document for the learning purpose.

Comment: for the time being I'll store the data to the storage but later I have to redirect this event stream to some API. So I do make this function production ready. pls help.

Comment: I have update the question to make it more relevant.

Comment: @Stark, Glad to know that you have met your first goal. But on stack overflow, it's one post for one question. So if you have more new questions, pls post a new one instead of asking all in one question. If you want to append contents, you should use Azure append blob to do so:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.appendblobservice.appendblobservice?view=azure-python-previous

Comment: @Stark and if you want to place to blob to some other path just try this code would be ok:`blob_client = BlobClient.from_connection_string(storage_connection_string,container_name,'2021/06/11' + ".<file extension you want>")` You can use datetime:https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html to get current year,month and  date easily.

Comment: @Stark , if my post is helpful, pls click the checkmark beside my answer to accept it. And if you have any more questions, just post a new one and let me know the link, I am glad to help:)

Comment: My data is landing to some other blob container instead of my defined container. Also, the data should be save as a text file but it is getting saved as blob type. can you please check my function.json and local.settings.json file.
Kindly have a look at the screenshot. I will accept your solution once it works perfectly. Incomplete solution may lead to confusion and doubt to other community members. Apologies if I am wrong.

Comment: @Stark, Yes, I have seen your screenshot before and It works as excepted: event content has been write into your containers. There is one question: I can understand that your data will be written into different containers, but how to decide which container the data write to? If a container not exists, we need to create it first.

Comment: yes.. we have to provide the container name in the code itself. if the container does not exist it should create a new one and then write..

Comment: but in my case nothing is working correctly that is why I have share the code snippet for the function.json and local.setting.json files  :( pls help

Comment: if you share the configurations for the above two files then it can resolve the error.

Comment: @Stark Oh, yes, my fault, I did not noticed that there is something worng with your `function.json` I have shared mine in my answer. I also updated the function code so that it will use append blob to write data and store blobs to folder by `container/year/month/day` hope it helps :)

Comment: @Stark , How's going? Has your issue got resolved?

Comment: yes.. it is working.. thanks a ton.. accepted and +1 for your kind gesture to help newbies :) but still a lots of things need to address like how I can make this code production ready.. can you please suggest any book or blog for the implementation of functions using python. also for the event hub.. thanks

Comment: @Stark, I think official doc is helpful:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/ and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?tabs=application-level , if you have any more questions , just post a question and let me know the link, I'll look into it.